# Help Identifying these trees and can they grow in pots?

Tags: identification, trees, flowers

I saw these two trees, and I'm just wondering what trees these are.

Can they grow in pots? We live in the tropics, so they would be outdoors receiving sun all the time. And they would be in 85-100F heat.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No is the short answer - if you want tree like plants in pots,  you need to choose small varieties, or those on dwarfing root stocks.

Comment: Or potentially grow them as bonsai.

Answer (score 3):

In pots? A large tree needs large roots. Every leave needs water, every part of the plant requires nutrients.  So I would say it would be impossible.

Note: olive tree could be placed in a large pot, but: 1- olive trees are not so large as in your picture, 2- the foliage is coriaceous, and in general a very slow growing plant (the plant you see could have various centuries), so totally different.  I have lemon tree in pots, but they are also very small (less than 2 meters tall) and slow growing.  Note: lemon and olive lives naturally in dry places.